# warning from read_excel function

Tags: r, r-package

It shows the error that :read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  :
Expecting numeric in G1659 / R1659C7: got 'Coverage'

Is there anyone facing this issue before?

```
excel1<-read_excel("excelsheet1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Can you try `read_excel("excelsheet1.xlsx", col_types = "text")`

Comment: Thanks akrun. it works . You could write in the answer and I will vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `col_types` to `"text"`

```
read_excel("excelsheet1.xlsx", col_types = "text")
```